# How to use css only H2 Tag? Site is considering website title also H2 tag and changing its style as well

Tags: css

Below CSS is executing to website title as well (does that mean that title is also considered as H2 if yes (how to solve that), or is it good for SEO to let it be as it is.

```
body.single-post h2 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #2196f3;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}
```

Comment: SEO doesn't care about CSS, and a H2 will always be a H2 no matter what CSS you use to style it, even if it's styled to look like a H1 or H3. If it's just SEO you're concerned about there's better stacks for that, e.g. the webmasters stack, pure frontend questions are off topic here

Comment: Make your CSS selector more specific... ...`body.single-post article .entry-header > h2{}`  as an example... ...you'll have to check your own markup though to figure out what it actually should be.  My example is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that this CSS is being applied to your page's main title tag too ?
if yes than your page's title is H2 instead of H1.
The main page title should be H1 for good SEO.

Comment: Not to main title but the site title something like "A digital blog" written under the logo. Thanks guys. Problem solved with something like body.single-post, or .post thanks.